# Is it possible to prevent child elements from being deleted when their parent is contentEditable?

Tags: javascript, css, html

When an element is `contentEditable`, its child elements can be deleted. If one of those child elements is *not* `contentEditable`, the content of the child cannot be edited, but the element itself can still be deleted. You can see this demonstrated in the following example.

**Is it possible to prevent these child elements from being deleted?**

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 300px;
}

span {
  color: #999;
}
```

```html
<div contentEditable="true">Hello <span contentEditable="false">world</span>!</div>
```

Comment: Good question! The only thing I can think of is to actually create seperate divs, and mark the outer ones as contentEditable: `<div><span contentEditable="true">Hello </span><span contentEditable="false">world</span><span contentEditable="true">!</span></div>`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Though that would technically work, it would result in a cumbersome UX that I'm hoping to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use classes, it would be easy.

```
<div class="contentEditable">Hello <span class="contentNotEditable">world</span>!</div>
<div class="saveContent" style="display: none;"></div>
```

Javascript/Jquery Part

```
<script>
$(".contentEditable").on("click",function(){
 // make blank .saveContent
 $(".saveContent").html("");

 // copy all contentNotEditable class which inside selected contentEditable class.
 $( this ).find(".contentNotEditable").clone().appendTo( ".saveContent" );

 // make blank contentEditable
 $( this ).html("");

 // clone contentNotEditable to contentEditable
 $( ".saveContent" ).find(".contentNotEditable").clone().appendTo( ".contentEditable" );
});
</script>
```

Comment: It works well in my tests. But it needs jquery. When you click on .contentEditable area, it shows only contentNotEditable area.

Comment: @Fatihd You should demonstrate it in a working code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to prevent these child elements from being deleted?

No, but here is an alternative solution.

#### Demo:

Since we can't have direct children, we need to create two separate elements.

```
<div class="editor">
  <label class="editor-label">You can't remove me</label>
  <div class="editor-area" contentEditable="true"></div>
</div>
```

Then, we remove **label** from the flow so it won't have any effects on **area**.

```
.editor {
  border: solid 1px #CCC;
  position: relative; // context for label
  line-height: 1.5;
}

.editor-area {
  min-height: 100px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.editor-label {
  position: absolute; // out of the flow
  padding: 5px 0 0 5px;
  user-select: none;
}
```

Finally, to make the caret start after the **label** text, we need to know its width and apply it to **area**'s `text-indent` value.

```
var editorLabel = document.querySelector('.editor-label');
var editorArea = document.querySelector('.editor-area');

var editorLabelRect = editorLabel.getBoundingClientRect();

editorArea.style.textIndent = editorLabelRect.width + 'px';
editorArea.innerHTML = '&nbsp';
```

---

**Complete code:**

```js
var editorLabel = document.querySelector('.editor-label');
var editorArea = document.querySelector('.editor-area');

var editorLabelRect = editorLabel.getBoundingClientRect();

editorArea.style.textIndent = editorLabelRect.width + 'px';
editorArea.innerHTML = '&nbsp';
```

```css
.editor {
  border: solid 1px #CCC;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

.editor-area {
  min-height: 100px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.editor-label {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 5px 0 0 5px;
  user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="editor">
  <label class="editor-label">You can't remove me</label>
  <div class="editor-area" contentEditable="true"></div>
</div>
```